# Convolution Product of 2 functions.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, laplace-transform, convolution

How do I find the covolution product of 2 function, like:

$\sin(2t-\sqrt(2)t) * \sin(\sqrt(2)t)$.

As best as I know the two function must have the same value, and I'm not really sure how to solve if they are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  $f(t)*g(t) = \int_0^tf(\tau)g(\tau-t)d\tau$ we have

$$
\sin(2t-\sqrt(2)t) * \sin(\sqrt(2)t) = \int_0^t\sin(2t-\sqrt(2)t)\sin(\sqrt(2)(\tau-t)) d\tau
$$